# Solving GAMS optimization for a specific range within a set

Tags: optimization, range, subset, gams-math

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem on GAMS, but only for a subset. Right now, i have a code that optimizes for all the elements of set t:

**t       time in hours            / 1 * 8760 /**

How do I run the optimization only for t from 1 to 3500, AND from 6500 to 8760 (for example)? FYI, all of my parameters data (from .csv) that i imported to GAMS have 8760 values. Here's a simple objective function to use:

**eObjFunc.. vZ =e= sum(t, v1(t));**

The simplest way I could think of is to edit all my .csv data so they only have the t values that I care for. In this case, define set t = 1 to 3500, 6500 to 8760. Then, just run the optimization.

However, I'm sure there's a smarter way to do this without having to modify my .csv data...
Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define subsets like this (assuming `t` is defined already as `1*8760`):

```
Set tt(t) /1*3500, 6500*8760/;
```

And then use `tt` instead of `t` in your equation:

```
eObjFunc.. vZ =e= sum(tt, v1(tt));
```